# Playa not returning data in template

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic

I have Playa installed on a clients site.
Playa 4.3.3 EE 2.5.5

The site was recently upgraded from EE 1.7.3

Everything works fine in the CP and publish forms.
Data is logging correctly in the exp_playa_relationships table.

Here is a very simple example:

```
<ul>
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages" entry_id="15974|14488" }
<li>{title}
{if promos != ""}
we have some data 
{/if}
{promos}
{promos-heading}
{/promos}
</li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

I get the message from the conditional, so the channel entries loop is finding data.

As a test I installed Playa in a dev environment, and of course all works as expected.

Any ideas what went south?  Any ee 1=>2 upgrade gotchas to look out for?

Comment: Jim, I'd love to have a look at this directly if possible. Any chance of Superadmin details? If so, please email them to support@pixelandtonic.com, and please reference this thread. :)

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? Is the version the same between your live and dev environments?

Comment: Lisa, email sent

Comment: Ian, php versions are the same (both sites are on the same server) php v 5.2.13

Comment: I compared queries on the site that works vs the one that doesn't.
This query is missing on the misbehaving site:
SELECT DISTINCT(rel.child_entry_id) AS entry_id
                            FROM exp_playa_relationships rel WHERE rel.parent_entry_id = 25 AND rel.parent_field_id = 13 ORDER BY rel.rel_order

Comment: Beuler.........?